# vue2 list of form elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a bunch of fields that I want to display as a long form, with each field allowing the user to select from a list of values for that field.

So the basic thing looks like this:

```
Vue.component('master-field', require('./Vue/MasterField').default);

new Vue({
    store,
    el: '#app',
    computed: {
        sourceFields: function () {
            return store.getters.visibleSource
        }
    }
})
```

then in the page, it does this to spit out the fields one by one, using the `sourceFields` data:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <master-field v-for="item in sourceFields" :key="item.id"></master-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I access the `item.id` from within the `master-field` component? If I try to do a `console.log(item.id)` from the `mounted` hook in the component it says item is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass it via props. [Props Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props)

pseudo example:

```
<my-component :info="someInfo" />
```

then in the component:

```
Vue.component('myComponent', {
  // declare the props
  props: ['info'],
  template: '<span>{{ info }}</span>'
})
```